# How does one interpret the random forest classifier from sci-kit learn?

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I know little on how random forest works.
Usually in classification I could fit the train data into the random forest classifier and ask to predict the test data.

Currently I am working on titanic data that is provided to me. This is a top rows of the data set and there are 1300(approx) rows.

`survived    pclass  sex age sibsp   parch   fare    embarked
0   1   1   female  29  0   0   211.3375    S
1   1   1   male    0.9167  1   2   151.55  S
2   0   1   female  2   1   2   151.55  S
3   0   1   male    30  1   2   151.55  S
4   0   1   female  25  1   2   151.55  S
5   1   1   male    48  0   0   26.55   S
6   1   1   female  63  1   0   77.9583 S
7   0   1   male    39  0   0   0   S
8   1   1   female  53  2   0   51.4792 S
9   0   1   male    71  0   0   49.5042 C
10  0   1   male    47  1   0   227.525 C
11  1   1   female  18  1   0   227.525 C
12  1   1   female  24  0   0   69.3    C
13  1   1   female  26  0   0   78.85   S`

There is no test data given. So I want random forest to predict the survival on entire data set and compare it with actual value (more like checking the accuracy score).

So what I have done is divide my complete dataset into test and train.
Train consists all the columns except survived and test consists survived column.

```
dfFeatures = df['survived']
dfTarget = dfCopy.drop('survived', 1)
```

Note: df is the entire dataset.

Here is the code that checks the score of randomforest

```
rfClf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_features=10)
rfClf = rfClf.fit(dfFeatures, dfTarget)
scoreForRf = rfClf.score(dfFeatures, dfTarget)
```

I get the score output with something like this

```
The accuracy score for random forest is :  0.983193277311
```

I am finding it little difficult to understand what is happening behind the code in above given code.

Does, it predict survival for all the tuples based upon other features (`dfFeatures`) and compare it with test data(`dfTarget`) and give the prediction score or does it randomly create train and test data based upon the train data provided and compare accuracy for test data it generated behind?

To be more precise, while calculating the accuracy score does it predict the survival for entire data set or just random partial data set?

Answer (score 1):

> To be more precise, while calculating the accuracy score does it
>   predict the survival for entire data set or just random partial data
>   set?

Entire data set.

> So what I have done is divide my complete dataset into test and train.
>   Train consists all the columns except survived and test consists
>   survived column.
>
> dfWithTestFeature = df['survived']
>
> dfWithTrainFeatures = dfCopy.drop('survived', 1)

This is not a train/test split. What you're calling 'train' dataset is actually features and 'test' - target. Train/test split is "horizontal", not "vertical". scikit-learn provides `train_test_split` function to do this:

```
y = df['survived']    
X = df.drop('survived', 1)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, t_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

# ... preprocessing ...

# Training:
rfClf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Testing:  
rfClf.score(X_test, y_test)
```

In this case model was trained using train subset (random 70% of the entire dataset) and then evaluated on the test subset (remaining 30%). More details can be found in [scikit-learn user guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).

Comment: Yes I do know there is train test split. But what if there is not test set? For me I want prediction on entire data set and I want to see how accurately a classifier classifies the data set. In this case random forest

Comment: This is not an answer and the question is not very clear. For any type of classification method you need a test set to evaluate performance of the classifier in an unbiased way.

Comment: @Cybercop "But what if there is not test set?" Then train/test split will provide you one. "I want prediction on entire data set and I want to see how accurately a classifier classifies the data set" Your code does exactly this. Note, however, that it's likely that this classifier won't perform nearly as good on the samples not used during the training.

Comment: @Alex so what you are saying is. My code actually predicts the survival on entire data set and gives score based on prediction of entire data set?

Comment: @MichaelChernick I agree that the question is a little confusing. I think the confusion is caused by incorrectly used terminology (train/test split vs. features and targets). I tried to answer the question asked in the last paragraph and then correct the author.

Comment: @Michael lets say I want to compare classifiers and see how accurately they predict survival on entire set. I could use decision tree, do cross validation and see actual value. I could do same for random forest but I though random forest would itself train and test data with 67% train and remaining test and build tree and it would do this for 100 trees in my case. And it would predict survival and check accuracy based on actual dataset

Comment: @AlexFilatov I am sorry for getting involved in this.  I no nothing about sci-kit learn and only a little about random forest even though I know a lot about classification trees. Saying that you can predict the test data does not make sense.  You may have made a contribution in your answer. At the time of my comment I was thinking that it could be expressed in comments but now I see it is probably better as an answer.

Comment: @Alex you are right I have indeed used wrong terminology thanks for pointing out. I will change that

Comment: @Cybercop You should do cross-validation for random forests as well. Yes, different trees in a forest are (by default) trained with random subsets of a train data (note that these subsets are usually different for different trees). But the forest as a whole still tries to fit the entire train dataset, so usual precautions to avoid overfitting apply.